# Query with variable

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

My table has a number of columns, namely G-L, each column contains some item data.
I need to write out the total number of each item, in each column, to another sheet.

Here is a simplified GGSheet and some data.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1j8NNdAgOVEzK-FovHJTcj6dnhDjrsdhAx6sVCaRBDa0/edit?usp=sharing

I will calculate the total items of each column using a `Query`, as written in A2. I then can just `copyValueToRange` the result. I will have to repeat this process with all of the order column.

To do this, I will have to pass the "next column" parameter into my Query each time I finished writing data.
As in A2 :

> `Select G .....`
>
> ProceedData()
>
> `Select H .....`
>
> ProceedData()

I'm currently stuck here. I can't figure out how to replace the column inside the query with the "next column" after I proceed data.

Though about string sustitute... but it seems google script doesn't have this function.

Any idea for this solution is very appreciated !

A small note : The number of column that contain data is vary depend on user input. It might come to 100 or more.

Comment: your spreadsheet cannot be accessed. Please fix permissions.

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited permission for the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cell A2 I entered this formula

```
=query(ArrayFormula(substitute(transpose(split(textjoin(" ", 1, trim(query(substitute(G2:L, " ", "_"),,rows(G2:G)))), " ")), "_", " ")), "Select Col1, Count(Col1) group by Col1 label Count(Col1)''")
```

See if that works for you?

Comment: Thank you very much. In my real table, each column is a purchase order from customers in a month, the items in that order are stored in that column, hence the need of storing which order ordered which item.
While I need to write out the total item of each column separately for checking and storing purpose --, which is why I asked for the query to run in each column, I do need to do a total calculation, and your answer solved that matter for me. I think it's good enough for me to work right now...